# how to get Current Tag ID in zpl command? I get current TagID.my command is including Printing and return tag id to host computer

Tags: rfid, zpl-ii

^XA
^RFR,H,2,12,1
^FN1^FS
^HV1,,Tag ID : ^FS
^XZ

this is my zpl command.It is printing and return tag id to host computer.
I just want only return tag id to host computer.
I don't want to print.
I want only to read tag id.
Please Sample Code for this.

I tried command . but i can't explain this.please solved code for this problem.